# Design Responsivo

Tags: css3, layout-responsivo, media-queries

Tenho duas dúvidas aqui com design responsivo.

A primeira é em relação ao código que segue:

```
 <link rel="stylesheet" media="only screen and(min=width: 1366px)"
href="css/deskmax.css"  />
```

porque quando crio o CSS assim ele não abre no navegador?

arquivo deskmax.css

```
 @media screen and (min-width: 1366px) and (max-width: 1920px) {

 conteúdo css do site

}
```

Eu faço tudo mais só funciona se eu tirar o `@media screen` do código com link; eu preciso deixar no css sem `@media` ou posso deixar assim mesmo?

Segunda dúvida com CSS em `@media` para design responsivo é, crio o css só dentro dos `@media querys` ou eu tenho que cria-lo antes todo, sem o `@media` e depois dentro do `@media` para reajustar?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Nesse site tem um resumo sobre o que significa cada propriedade das Medias Querys.
http://tableless.com.br/introducao-sobre-media-queries/

Mas não se preocupe **demais** com isso.

Agora, o que vem primeiro ? Depende de seu desenvolvimento.

Umas das práticas mais usadas hoje é o Mobile First. Ou seja, você começa seu CSS programando para dispositivos móveis e vai usando as **medias querys** para ajustar sua página para aparelhos maiores até o FULL HD.

A prática Mobile First economiza muitas linhas de códigos.

Comment: Bem eu to experimentando o responsivo, estou aprendendo ainda mais eu comecei da menor resolução no caso eu coloquei 768px, só não entendi o pq não emula o código quando separo no link os dois CSS agora quando junto ele emula direitinho. Quem me ensinou fez um arquivo para cada CSS e colocou dentro dos arquivos o media e no link a condição para abrir aquele css ou seja media... OBG o link ta ajudando

Comment: Por que Mobile First economizaria linhas de código?

Comment: Economiza mais do que fazer Mobile Full. Mobile Full você trabalharia com `screen max-width`. Teria que fazer todo estilo `CSS` pra chegar onde quer. Com `screen min-width` você digita pouco em comparação com `screen max-width`, começa da menor resolução para a maior. É melhor manutenibilidade também.

Answer (score -1):

sou novo aqui e tbm estou pesquisando por isso você pode usar da seguinte forma :

```
< meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

colocar isso na sua pagina INDEX.

e no css dessa forma para definir o tamanho dos pixels de cada dispositivo sabendo que cada um dispositvo tem um certo tamanho

```
@media(max-width:750px){
```